# Ember Data - how to findBy with an associated hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two objects User and Post. A user has many posts and a post belongs to a user.

How do I, within the user controller, use findBy or another method to get to a featured post with the posts array??

Here is how I implemented the UserController; however, the featuredPost computed property is coming back as undefined. Is this best approach? If so, what am I missing?

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  client: DS.belongsTo('App.Client', { async: true }),
  posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post', { async: true })
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  client: DS.belongsTo('App.Client', { async: true }),
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User', { async: true }),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  isFeatured: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['post'],
  posts: (function() {
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
      content: this.get('content.posts')
    });
  }).property('content.posts'),

  featuredPost: (function() {
    return this.get('content.posts').findBy('isFeatured', true)
  }).property('content.featuredPost'),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_filterBy

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  featuredPost: Ember.computed.filterBy('posts', 'isFeatured', true)
});
```

Also, in

```
featuredPost: (function() {
  return this.get('content.posts').findBy('isFeatured', true);
}).property('content.featuredPost')//should be observing 'posts'
```

You are basically observing content.featuredPost but from what youve mentioned that property doesnt exist, the property you should be observing is 'posts'. This is a mistake that i made when i was learning ember too, so felt like pointing out. Also using content is optional, you can directly observe the model associated with controller.

Also From doc, findBy seems to return just first item that matches the passed value, not all of them. So to get first match it should be

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  featuredPost: function() {
    return this.get('posts').findBy('isFeatured', true);
  }.property('posts')//assuming user model hasMany relation to posts
});
```

Also I would go with the latest version of ember data and make following changes:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  client: DS.belongsTo('client', { async: true }),
  posts: DS.hasMany('post', { async: true })
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  client: DS.belongsTo('client', { async: true }),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  isFeatured: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

This would be good read : https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

And here is a bare minimum working example : http://jsbin.com/disimilu/5/edit

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This a great step in the right direction; however, I think Ember.computed.filterBy returns an array, I was just hoping for the first result. I tried finding documentation for the ArrayComputedProperty that it returned, but couldn't find a helpful method. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok sorry, i assumed you were looking for an array. Ill update my answer.

Comment: That's similar to what I had before with the same unexpected result of undefined :(

Comment: The model association looks like this: posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post', { async: true })

Comment: Can you put the code snippet for the user model too, just to get an idea. You should have something like posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async:true}), if your post model is defined as App.Post = ...., you dont need App.Post. See that 'post' is all small case and singular.

Comment: If that still doesnt help, can you make a jsbin and post it and we can figure out whats going on.

Comment: I've updated my post with my two models as well, let me know if something is missing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51506/discussion-between-nelsonw-and-deewendra-shrestha)